# Recommendation for machine to replace 2017 iMac for aspiring data scientist

Tags: laptop, desktop, multiple-monitors

thanks for your time. My iMac can be really slow to access memory. I have tried to reinstall the OS multiple times with no great result. Basically I think the memory handling is really bad. My macbook pro on the other hand runs great.

But the monitor on the iMac is beautiful. I'm not crazy about either keyboard.

And I'm in the process of learning data analysis/science. So monitor quality and keyboard are important.

Here are some things I'm considering.

1. Get a desktop monitor for the macbook and deal with the keyboard being less than optimally comfortable. I could also afford a separate travel monitor that way and get double screens when away from home.
2. Get another iMac or a mac mini and a monitor.
3. Build a linux machine. I've been using mac OS since 2001, so maybe I should learn something new. Especially if this will help with ML or other DA/DS stuff further down the road. I have no idea how to do this, but could learn.

Any ideas are appreciated. I would like to do this without making some expensive mistake.

Answer (score 0):

All three options are great ideas, so I'll go over each one of them.

1. This would work, but you would be using laptop components as a desktop, so you won't get desktop-level performance.  If you're happy with the way your MacBook performs, then this is the ideal option.  With the money that you save not having to buy a new computer, you could buy a magic keyboard/trackpad/mouse.
2. The new M1 iMac is a great computer, but can only get up to 16GB of ram.  If this is ok with you, then I would highly recommend it.  Otherwise I would wait until the M2 iMacs come out so you can get more ram.  At this time, I would not buy an intel based mac because they are going to be phased out in the next few years and you won't want to be forced to upgrade when that time comes.
3. This is also a great idea.  Linux is a great operating system for everyone.  I helped a senior install and use Ubuntu and she loves it, but I also know heavy programmers who use Linux and love it.  The only drawback is software support.  Certain software that you need to have on a computer may not be on Linux yet.  Also, the process of building a computer is a great experience!  It isn't extremely difficult, but it is a great way to learn the internal components of a computer.

Basically, do whichever one you want.  I would personally just buy an external monitor and keyboard/mouse to save money, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer building a Linux machiene, I have one too. But Linux has stupid glitches sometimes. Getting a new iMac is too expensive for me, so I would rule that out too. So I would then use option one, if you don't like glitches.